# internal class access c#

Tags: c#, class, internal

This maybe a very simple question! But I have been scratching my head for an hour now! I have two files as below:

1. Assembly1.cs
2. Program.cs

I thought when I use `internal` keyword before a class name I won't be able to instantiate it in other classes, right?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx

But why am I not getting an error message for this here? I maybe missing something very obvious here.

```
// Assembly1.cs
namespace InternalTest
{
    internal sealed class BaseClass 
    {
        public static int intM = 0;
    }
}


// Program.cs
using System;

namespace InternalTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var myBase = new BaseClass();

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly" - you link to the answer to your question.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot I still don't get it. In the same article there is this first example! There it says that it should result in error.

Comment: The files in the examples are in separate assemblies, yours aren't.

Comment: @Vahid : you have two files and they are in same assembly.you don't have them in two different assembly.so that's the reason you are not getting the error.Having two different files does not mean two different assemblies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internal means class is accessible within the assembly.Above class is in same assembly hence no error.If you want to see the error then follow below step

1) Create Library project

2) Create Base Class in that project

3) Create Console project

4) Add reference of first project dll

5) Now try to create instance, you will see the error

**Additional Info**

If you want to access internal members in your console project then add below attribute in AssemblyInfo.cs of Library project

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("[AssemblyNameOfConsoleProject]")]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just learned how to do it! It is very embarrassing I have done a large scale application on my own yet I had forgotten this very simple rule!

Answer (score -2):

Because both classes are on the same namespace.

```
//InternalTest
namespace InternalTest
{
internal sealed class BaseClass 
{
    public static int intM = 0;
}
}

//the same here InternalTest
namespace InternalTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I should put them in separate projects if I need to have them in separate namespaces?

Comment: `internal` does not change behavior based on namespaces, it it based purely on which assembly the classes are defined in.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot I need to define different project then right?

Comment: @Vahid The most straight-forward way to create multiple assemblies is to define separate projects, yes.

Comment: Thanks very much. They can'be defined in the same project then I suspect?

Comment: @Vahid One project can contain multiple assemblies. In Unity they are defined with assembly definition files, but they also exist in general C# applications.