# Trying to figure out how to unit test a service with dependencies using Xunit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, autofac, xunit

Hey StackOverflow experts. Let me first state that I am fairly new to this whole programmig thing. With that said, I am trying to figure out to wire up the dependncies I have setup in AutoFac for use in a Xunit Test Project.

I have 4 layers layers
Domain
Application
Infrastructure
WebUI

I have services in the Infrastructure Layer that are marked as internal to prevent use from the Application Layer Directly. This should be fine as long as I can figure out some way to get the dependencies from the current container inside my SUT.

Thanks

Read the following which gave me some ideas but have not found a solution.
https://medium.com/c-sharp-progarmming/asp-net-core-unit-testing-of-dependency-injection-with-iservicecolletion-e3ceb9295e46
https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/moq.html

For reference here is what my container looks like so far.

```
public static class AutoFacLoader {
    public static string ? ConnectionString {
            get;
            set;
    }
    public static string ? AppSettingsName {
            get;
            set;
    }
    public static ContainerBuilder BuildContainer(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder) {
            /* AutoFac Module Registration */
            containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new NHibernateModule {
                    ConnectionString = ConnectionString
            });

            containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new AppSettingsModule {
                    AppSettingsName = "Default"
            });

            containerBuilder.RegisterType < Argon2PasswordHasher >
                    ().As < IArgon2PasswordHasher > ().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType < UserService > ().As < IUserService >
                    ().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType < ClaimService >
                    ().As < IClaimService >
                    ().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType < UserClaimService >
                    ().As < IUserClaimService > ().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType < ProfileService >
                    ().As < IProfileService > ().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType < EmailService >
                    ().As < IEmailService >
                    ().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            containerBuilder.RegisterType < AuthenticationService >
                    ().As < IAuthenticationService > ().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType < DnsService > ().As < IDnsService >
                    ().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType < CountryService >
                    ().As < ICountryService > ().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            containerBuilder.RegisterAutoMapper(typeof (DataLayerMappingProfile).Assembly);

            return containerBuilder;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of one of the classes that I have wired up in AutoFac. You will see it in the above code being registered.

```
internal sealed class UserService: IUserService
{
  private readonly IArgon2PasswordHasher _argon2PasswordHasher;
  private readonly ILogger _logger;
  private readonly IMapper _mapper;
  private readonly ISession _session;

  public UserService(ISession session, IArgon2PasswordHasher 
       argon2PasswordHasher,
      ILogger logger, IMapper mapper) {
      _session = session;
      _argon2PasswordHasher = argon2PasswordHasher;
      _logger = logger;
      _mapper = mapper;
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// Gets a list of all users
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="page">Test</param>
  /// <param name="pageSize"></param>
  /// <param name="active"></param>
  /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
  /// <returns>List<UserDto></UserDto></returns>
  public async Task < IList < UserDto >> GetUsersAsync(int page, 
  int pageSize, bool active,
      CancellationToken cancellationToken =
      default) {
      cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

      using
      var transaction = _session.BeginTransaction();
      try {
          var userDtoList = new List < UserDto > ();
          var userList = await _session.QueryOver < User > ()
              .Where(x => x.Active == active)
              .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
              .Take(pageSize)
              .Cacheable()
              .CacheMode(CacheMode.Normal)
              .ListAsync < User > (cancellationToken);

          return _mapper.Map(userList, userDtoList);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          _logger.Error(e.Message);
          if (transaction != null) await 
transaction.RollbackAsync(cancellationToken);
      } finally {
          if (transaction != null) await 
transaction.CommitAsync(cancellationToken);
      }

      return new List < UserDto > ();
  }
}
```

I am not attempting to test this class directly I want to inject it into my test I guess you could say. But the test project obviously has no knowledge of the container.

Comment: You're not supposed to directly test private or internal classes; they can be tested through your public API. If you have code that's hard to test via that public API, it's a code smell that you might have a design that's test-unfriendly that needs to be refactored.

Comment: They are internal to prevent just that sir. This is why I am looking to use the dependencies already wired up in AutoFac. Public Interface, Internal sealed class. It was strongly reccomnded that I use that approach so nothing in the application layer can use a class from the infrastucture layer. The only use is for wiring up AutoFac which works quite nicely so far.

Comment: Even if my UserService class were not internal I still have to satisfy the constructor. I am not looking forward to configuring Nhibernate and all of that other stuff just to unit test my UserService. That seems silly.

Comment: with internal sealed class, does your application work without any issues?

Comment: It works great. I inject into the ctor and have no issues at all. It is internal so it cant be instantiated directly from the Infrastructure layer as WebUI and infrastructure should not be dependant on each other. Well except for setting up the AutoFac container thats it.

Comment: You might want to make the internal class visible to the test project. check answer of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35244310/internal-class-access-c-sharp. Even when you make the internal class visible to the test project, you still have to create mocks of the dependencies to test it.

Comment: That would defeat the purpose though. What make it temporarly visible and cross boundaries just for testing??? Doesn't sit well. All of my services are internal the interfaces are not and are sitting inside the Application Layer.

Comment: Then you need to resolve the class from Autofac using the same way as you are resolving in the actual application. But, if you have to initialize the entire dependency map to create a class object in Unit test, then that's not Unit test.

Comment: Well all of the registrations for AutoFac you see in my post pretty much use an ISession an ILogger, and IMapper for AutoMapper. Not a gazillion dependencies. But I cant Mok something I cant see so maybe I need to rethink some of this. Just figured there would be a "Correct" way to do this.